# Convert regexp from php to javascript (lookback assertion)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regexp to replace embedded RGB colors {rrggbb} (always exactly 6 characters enclosed in curly brackets) into html span tags:
`{([a-fA-F0-9]+)}((?>[^{]*{?(?!(?1)}))*)`

It was used like this:

`preg_replace('~{([a-fA-F0-9]+)}((?>[^{]*{?(?!(?1)}))*)~',
        '<span style="color: #$1">$2</span>', $text);`

It worked well with preg_replace in php, but when trying to use it in javascript I'm getting a syntax error (? The preceding token is not quantifiable)

How can I make it work in javascript?

Note I have another regexp: `{([a-fA-F0-9]{6})\}([^\{]+)` which works, however if I do something like this: `{ff0000}red text {some text that isn't a color} {00ff00}blue text` I'm getting an output of: `<span style="color: #ff0000">red text </span>{some text that isn't a color} <span style="color: #00ff00">blue text</span>`, note that `{some text that isn't a color}` isn't wrapped in any `span` tag, while it still should be in the previous tag. I dont know how to fix it though.

Comment: Sure, JS regexp does not support subroutines.What exactly did you try?

Comment: Well I'm really a noob on regex and couldn't do much, I have another regexp: `{([a-fA-F0-9]{6})\}([^\{]+)` which works, however if I do something like this: `{ff0000}red text {some text that isn't a color} {00ff00}blue text` I'm getting an output of: `<span style="color: #ff0000">red text </span>{some text that isn't a color} <span style="color: #00ff00">blue text</span>`, note that {some text that isn't a color} isn't wrapped in any span tag, while it still should be in the previous tag. I dont know how to fix it though.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `$text` looks like in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS regexp does not support subroutines, but you may define a block as a variable, and build a pattern dynamically. Also, the `(?>[^{]*{?(?!(?1)}))*` part is too cryptic (and contains an atomic group  `(?>...)` that is not supported by JS RegExp, either), and what it does is just matches any 0+ chars other than `{` that is not followed with hex chars up to the closing `}` and so on up to the RGB pattern (a kind of an unroll-the-loop principle variation).

JS equivalent is

```js
var s = "{ff0000}red text {some text that isn't a color} {00ff00}blue text";
var xdigit = "[a-fA-F0-9]+";
var result = s.replace(new RegExp("{("+xdigit+")}([^{]*(?:{(?!"+xdigit+"})[^{]*)*)", "g"), '<span style="color: #$1">$2</span>');
console.log(result);
```

The pattern used is

```
/{([a-fA-F0-9]+)}([^{]*(?:{(?![a-fA-F0-9]+})[^{]*)*)/g
```

See the [JS regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/MQfcTG/1).

- `{` - a `{` char
- `([a-fA-F0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more (use `{6}` to only match 6) hex chars
- `}` - a `}` char
- `([^{]*(?:{(?![a-fA-F0-9]+})[^{]*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `[^{]*` - any 0+ chars other than `{`
  - `(?:{(?![a-fA-F0-9]+})[^{]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of the following sequence of patterns:

    - `{` - a `{` that is....
    - `(?![a-fA-F0-9]+})` - not followed with 1+ hex chars and then a `}`
    - `[^{]*` - any 0+ chars other than `{`

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm, I just needed to limit the match to 6 characters.

Comment: @Vojthas Yeah, then use `var xdigit = "[a-fA-F0-9]{6}";`